# How to access and iterate through contentView.subviews in UITableView when cells are not visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating a form in a UITableView, when I go to collect all the data in the table using for (UIView *view in  cell.contentView.subviews){} Even though it iterates through every cell in the UITableView, It can't see any of the data in the rows that aren't yet visible. How can I access this data?

I tried adding scrollToRowAtIndexPath in the vain hope that it would load the visible rows but to no avail.

```
 for (int i=0; i < countArray.count; i++) { //count needs to be for the cells entire tableView

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: i inSection: 0]; //create NSIndexPath for each cell in section 0
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; //iterating through each cell available in table
        NSLog(@"iterationing through cell \"%i\"",indexPath.row);

         [self.table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"moving view to \"%i\"",indexPath.row);

        for (UIView *view in  cell.contentView.subviews){ //find views within cell.contentview

            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){ // narrow those views down to anything with class UITextField

                UITextField* txtField = (UITextField *)view; // instantiate the UITextField

                if (txtField.tag == 201) { //find the tag of the instantiated UITextField
                    if (dataSwitch == 0) { //we are collecting data
                        [tmpArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtField.text]];
                    }else if (dataSwitch == 1) { //we are distributing data
                        txtField.text = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:i];
                    }
                }
                else if (txtField.tag == 202) { //find the tag of the instantiated UITextField
                    if (dataSwitch == 0) { //we are collecting data
                        [tmpArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtField.text]];
                    }else if (dataSwitch == 1) { //we are distributing data
                        txtField.text = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:i];
                    }
                }
                else if (txtField.tag == 203) { //find the tag of the instantiated UITextField
                    if (dataSwitch == 0) { //we are collecting data
                        [tmpArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtField.text]];
                    }else if (dataSwitch == 1) { //we are distributing data
                        txtField.text = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:i];
                    }
                }
                else if (txtField.tag == 204) { //find the tag of the instantiated UITextField
                    if (dataSwitch == 0) { //we are collecting data
                        [tmpArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtField.text]];
                    }else if (dataSwitch == 1) { //we are distributing data
                        txtField.text = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:i];
                    }
                }
                else if (txtField.tag == 205) { //find the tag of the instantiated UITextField
                    if (dataSwitch == 0) { //we are collecting data
                        [tmpArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtField.text]];
                    }else if (dataSwitch == 1) { //we are distributing data
                        txtField.text = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:i];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Data is being lost %@ with tag %i",[tmpArray objectAtIndex:i], txtField.tag);
                }
            }


            // End of isKindofClass
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){ // narrow those views down to anything with class UIImage
                UIImageView* image = (UIImageView *)view; // instantiate the UIImage

                if (dataSwitch == 0) { //we are collecting data
                    [tmpArray addObject:image];
                    NSLog(@"collecting image data and storing in %i",i);

                }else if (dataSwitch == 1) { //we are distributing data
                    image = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:i];
                }
            }



            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){ // narrow those views down to anything with class UILabel
                UILabel* label = (UILabel *)view; // instantiate the UILabel

                 if (label.tag == 301) { //find the tag of the instantiated UILabel

                     if (dataSwitch == 0) { //we are collecting data
                        [tmpLabelArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",label.text]];
                        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",label.text]);
                    }
                }
            }



            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]){ // narrow those views down to anything with class UISegmentedControl
                UISegmentedControl* seg = (UISegmentedControl *)view; // instantiate the UISegmentedControl

                if (dataSwitch == 0) { //we are collecting data
                    [tmpArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",seg.selectedSegmentIndex]];


                }
            }
        } // End of Cell Sub View
    }// Counter Loop
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Nick.

*****edit*****

Here's what I ended up doing

Duncan C was right, grabbing the information like this isn't correct. It is possible to animate the tableview to bring the reusable cells into view and collect the data but it looks messy, this is a much cleaner method.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

 if(textField.tag >= 0 && textField.tag <= 10) {

      CGPoint location = [self.table convertPoint:textField.frame.origin fromView:textField.superview];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.table indexPathForRowAtPoint:location]; //get the indexPath of the textField.

      NSString *str1  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",stack];
      NSString *str2  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];
      NSString *str3  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textField.text];

      NSMutableArray *cellAnswer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:str1,str2,str3, nil];

    }
}
```

Comment: are you using for your UITableView content = static cells ? If not, you could not perform what you want, as cells are reuse for other contents, better found the data in your data source.

Comment: no they're not static. Gah! I thought this would be the case, do you know why you can't animate through the tableView and save the content as it appears on screen?

Comment: Even this code is a bit silly. In your textfieldDidEndEditing method, you get a pointer to the text field that the user just finished editing. You know the tag number. Why loop through 10 possible tags when a given field will only contain a single tag numbers? Get rid of the loop, and simply check to see if the text field's tag is in the proper range. If it is, use textField.tag as your i value, with no looping needed.

Comment: Thanks Duncan C I've edited the code again. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a conceptual misunderstanding of how table views work, and how you are supposed to use them. The cells that are not visible do not exist. A table view only creates those cells that are currently visible. As the user scrolls, the cells that are scrolled off the screen are put in the recycling queue, and then re-used as new cells for cells that are newly exposed.

Cells are view objects, and should not be used to save data. When a user enters data into a cell (types text into a text field, changes the value of a switch or slider, etc) you should immediately collect those changes and save them to the model that is displayed by the table view. Then, if a cell gets scrolled off-screen and discarded, you have already collected it's state data.

Comment: Yup you are right its a messy work around. Ended up using textFieldDidEndEditing then iterated through the textField tag using a simple for loop.

Comment: So you're looping through all the text fields in a cell in the textFieldDidEndEditing method and collecting all the user-edited values? That's better than what you were attempting before.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question showing what I did. So much better.